# Most optimal way for if structure with 3 possibilities

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What would be the most optimal way to write an if structure (or switch or case or w/e) with 3 possibilities.

```
if($tekst!=''){
$qry="tekst filled in";
}
elseif($aantal!=''){
$qry="aantal filled in";
}
elseif($aantal!=''&&$tekst!='')
{
$qry="both filled in";
}
```

Comment: This does not fit in stackoverflow. Your question will probably be closed. I'm just warning you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This does not fit in stackoverflow. Your question will probably be
>   closed. I'm just warning you

... just someone wanting coding style advice...

switch statement is not usable because of combined check ($aantal!=''&&$tekst!='').
so if/else statement is your best option (imho).
I would however write it as:

```
if($aantal && $tekst) {
   $qry="both filled in";
}
else if($tekst) {
    $qry="tekst filled in";
}
else if($aantal) {
    $qry="aantal filled in";
}
```

I personally find it more readable this way.

note: do write localization sensitive text to English before posting a question.

Comment: Doesn't your statement needs a 'else' case ? I mean, your last 'if' should be an 'else'  ?

Comment: is SHOULD be 'else' .. and not 'else if'. Just 'else'. you have one (1) last dime to try.

Comment: Well, isn't it a 3 way posibilities ( 1, the other one, all the others) ?

Answer (score 0):

Optimal in what sense?

One idea would be:

```
var r = [ [ undefined,  "tekst filled in" ],
          [ "aantal filled in", "both filled in" ]];

$qry = r[+($aantal!='')][+($tekst!='')];
```

`+` -operator is used to evaluate 'false' to 0, and 'true' to 1 for indexing.
R could be also defined as an object with keys 'true' and 'false':

```
r = { "true" : { "true": "Both filled in", "false": "tekst filled in" },
      "false" : { "true": "aantal filled in" } };
```

$qry = r[$aantal!=''][$tekst!=''];

Comment: sure, will work. but most of the time other read your code. Maintainability is very important while coding. Personally don't like write-only code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(something) {
    ...
}
else if(something-else-specific) { /* other specific case */
    ...
}
else { /* any other cases*/
   ...
}
```

That's all there is to be.